# Why does this return the correct value with Floats but not doubles?

Tags: c, types

```
float Raise2power(double base, int exponent){
    if(exponent==0){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        while (--exponent){
            base*=base;
        }
        return base;
    }
}
```

I changed the return type to float and this code works but when it was double before it returned garbage.

Comment: Won't this code return `10000` instead of `1000` for `Raise2power(10, 3)`?

Comment: This is not a power function. You're repeatedly *squaring* `base`.

Comment: And apart from the incorrect logic, your function yields similar results whether the return type is `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem must be in some code that you're not showing us.

First off, that's not a power function. You're repeatedly *squaring* `base`.

When I incorporate your function into a small complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

float Raise2power(double base, int exponent){
   if(exponent==0){
       return 1;
   }
   else {
        while (--exponent){
           base*=base;
        }
        return base;
   }
}

int main(void) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 5; i ++) {
        printf("Raise2power(10.0, %d) = %.1f\n", i, Raise2power(10.0, i));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get this output:

```
Raise2power(10.0, 0) = 1.0
Raise2power(10.0, 1) = 10.0
Raise2power(10.0, 2) = 100.0
Raise2power(10.0, 3) = 10000.0
Raise2power(10.0, 4) = 100000000.0
Raise2power(10.0, 5) = 10000000272564224.0
```

When I change `float Raise2power` to `double Raise2power`, I get this output:

```
Raise2power(10.0, 0) = 1.0
Raise2power(10.0, 1) = 10.0
Raise2power(10.0, 2) = 100.0
Raise2power(10.0, 3) = 10000.0
Raise2power(10.0, 4) = 100000000.0
Raise2power(10.0, 5) = 10000000000000000.0
```

Show us a complete program and its output.

**UPDATE:** In comments, you say you've fixed the bug and it's working now. I suspect those two things are unrelated; nothing in the code you've shown us should be producing garbage values -- unless you're doing something wrong somewhere else.

My best guess is that you had *defined* the function as returning `float` in one place, but *declared* it as returning `double` in another, or vice versa. The compiler, when it sees a call, would then assume that the result is of one type, when in fact it's of another type.

Either that, or you called the function without a visible declaration at all. For a pre-C99 compiler (such as Microsoft's), the compiler will assume that the return type is `int`, which again would yield garbage. But then you should get garbage either for `float` or for `double`.

The way to avoid that kind of problem is to *declare* the function in a header file, and `#include` that header both in the `.c` file that defines the function (so the compiler can check for consistency) and in any source file that contains a call to the function.

But again, this is just speculation, since you never gave us enough information to diagnose the problem.

Recommended reading: http://sscce.org/

Comment: After catching the bug it works fine in Visual Studio. Could be an issue with how I setup Netbeans either the cygwin install or gcc. Thanks Everybody for catching the bug.

Comment: Your right I thought it was in the header file and it wasn't but it is in the new code.

Comment: @West: So that's your problem; when the compiler processed the call to your function, it didn't know how it was defined. You *should* have gotten a warning about that. If you did, you should have paid attention to it; if not, you need to fix the way you invoke your compiler so it gives you more warnings.